# Mage_PageCache - External full page cache

Tags: cache, magento-community, full-page-cache

So in Community Edition there is an option under `System->Configuration->System->External Full Page Cache Settings` that appears to be offering a full page cache using Zend Cache.

[image: Full page cache config]

When you set these values you then get a new button on the cache page to clear this cache.

[image: Cache page]

So my question is this, after just discovering this recently. What the heck? Does it work? Why have this in CE and then remove it in EE and have a completely different module? Does anyone actually use it?

*Note: this module is not in the EE release*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some digging around and some useful feedback on twitter I appear to have found some stuff out.

By default this is set-up to use a Zend Server feature `Page Cache`. It appears to be a feature almost completely set-up on the server with the only things in Magento being.

A clean function that calls. `page_cache_remove_all_cached_contents`

```
public function clean()
{
    if (extension_loaded('Zend Page Cache') && function_exists('page_cache_remove_all_cached_contents')) {
        page_cache_remove_all_cached_contents();
    }
}
```

And the enabling and disabling the extension from the admin section, but all this does is show/hide the button on the cache page.

As you can see from the clean function if uses the extension `Zend Page Cache`, but the class does implement the interface `Mage_PageCache_Model_Control_Interface` so it does seem like it has been built with the possibility to be used with other external caching systems and not just Zend server.

*Note: I have never used this or Zend server*

Comment: Great find, to answer the question I think it's safe to assume it was pulled due to EE having its own FPC module built-in.