# Add the CE module Mage_PageCache to an EE instance

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, magento-community, full-page-cache, enterprise-1.14

I have a Varnish module that uses the interface provided by `Mage_PageCache`. Unfortunately, `Mage_PageCache` exists *only* in CE. The reason is probably that EE has its own `PageCache` module as a complete replacement (see: [Mage_PageCache - External full page cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29513/mage-pagecache-external-full-page-cache)), but the Enterprise Full Page Cache does not provide an interface for external caches, so I cannot use it in the same way.

Now I want to use this Varnish module in a Magento Enterprise instance.

I could rewrite it to work as a standalone module (after all, `Mage_PageCache` doesn't *do* much on its own). But I would like to know if there are any known problems with `Mage_PageCache` and Magento EE, especially conflicts with the `Enterprise_PageCache` module:

**Is is possible/safe to add `Mage_PageCache` to a Magento Enterprise installation?**

Ideally, Enterprise FPC should still be active additionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add `Mage_PageCache` from Magento CE 1.9.2 to Magento EE 1.14.2 without further modification, but I did not activate the Enterprise FPC (it was not compatible with the Varnish module, so I cannot say where there might be other incompatibilities)